# looping through a dynamically allocated matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

So I have looked through some online questions to figure out how to setup and fill a dynamic multidimensional array and I thought I had it down but for some reason my function will not access the anything past the first(0) column. For my test I put in a 2X2 array:

```
2 2 (part of another function that gives the size of the matrix)
1 2
3 4
```

When I debug it I only get

```
1 random# from initializing the array
3 random# from initializing the array
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with this piece of code, I am also new to C++.

```
double* matrix_read(const int m, const int n)
{
double **mat = new double*[m];

for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
    mat[j] = new double[n];
}
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {

        cin >> mat[i][j];
    }
}
double debug = mat[2][2];
return *mat;
}
```

Inside the main function this is what I send to the function.

```
int x, y, m, n;
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        double *mat_a = matrix_read(x, y);
        cin >> m; //2nd matrix read in
        cin >> n;
        double *mat_b = matrix_read(m, n);
```

Comment: @P0W I added the function call and how I pass the parameters to the function. The (double debug = mat[2][2]) was a debug output I tried to read and got an error.

Comment: You return only the first line of the matrix `return *mat;` instead of the whole matrix. Besides `mat[2][2]` is an out of bounds access for your 2x2 array.

Comment: @aslg thank you, sorry I am having a frustrating day trying to figure this out totally forgot the bounds of an array start at 0. Thanks for the feedback, I will look in returning a full matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is represented as an array of pointers, each pointer in the array points, in turn, to an array of doubles. Each of these arrays are contiguous in memory, but not among themselves. This means that, `mat[0][0]` is right before `mat[0][1]` in memory. But `mat[1][0]` may be in a completely different location.

By returning only the first line of your matrix, `*mat` (the same as `mat[0]`), you will lose information. All you have access to is the first line.

You should return the whole matrix.

```
double** matrix_read(...) {
    ...
    return mat;
}
```

(Edit: Besides, someone will have to delete the matrix later.. and they have to delete several arrays, ugh. You should make a structure wrapper for matrices, or use a single array, or use a vector of vectors)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just found out that I can't do it that way and I need to use 1D arrays and treat them like 2D. I guess I will spend the time researching how to do that. Again thank you for the help.